# Generate dynamic rows and flag based on certain condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to generate a dynamic SQL result (not based on any tables).

This is what I have right now:

```
SELECT datepart(year,getdate()) as [VALUE], 
'datepart(year,getdate()) as [DESCRIPTION], null as DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Which results in:

```
VALUE       DESCRIPTION DEFAULT_VALUE
----------- ----------- -------------
2014        2014        NULL
```

My goal:

```
VALUE       DESCRIPTION DEFAULT_VALUE
----------- ----------- -------------
2013        2013        False  
2014        2014        True
2015        2015        False
```

So what I would like to know is if there is any way to add a new column, `DEFAULT_VALUE`, and make it clever enough to set the default value to the current year?

Comment: What should determine whether `True` or `False` are to be returned in `DEFAULT_VALUE`, based on the year only?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller In this example it would only be true if it's the current year.

Comment: Well, @Gibson's answer seems to make it. Is this what you want?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller To an extent, but it only returns one row.

Comment: @Johan how may rows do you want to see?

Comment: @Gibson Something like my last example would be great. So 3 rows perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depending on how fancy you want to get and without knowing some more of the underlining problem. This should work

```
declare @result table (VALUE int, DESCRIPTION int, DEFAULT_VALUE char(5))

declare @year int = -1
declare @workingYear datetime

select  @workingYear = dateadd(year, @year, getdate())

while @year < 2
begin

select  @workingYear = dateadd(year, @year, getdate())

    insert into @result values (
    datepart(year,@workingYear), 
    datepart(year,@workingYear),  
    case 
        when (datepart(year,@workingYear) = datepart(year,getdate())) then 
            'True'
        else
            'False'
        end)
set @year = @year + 1
end

select * from @result
```

This yields the results

```
    VALUE   DESCRIPTION DEFAULT_VALUE
    2013    2013        False
    2014    2014        True 
    2015    2015        False
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the other 2 rows?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Tally Table. Here is the link:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

```
declare @result table(
    value int,
    description int,
    default_value varchar(5)
)

declare @current_year int
set @current_year = datepart(year,getDate())

-- create your tally table --
with 
    e1 as(select 1 as N union all select 1), -- 2 rows
    e2 as(select 1 as N from e1 as a, e1 as b), -- 4 rows
    e3 as(select 1 as N from e2 as a, e2 as b), -- 16 rows
    e4 as(select 1 as N from e3 as a, e3 as b), -- 256 rows
    e5 as(select 1 as N from e4 as a, e4 as b), -- 65536 rows
    tally as (select row_number() over(order by N) as N from e5
)
insert into @result
select top 3 -- replace 3 with number of rows you want
    N, 
    N,
    case
        when N = @current_year then 'True'
        else 'False'
    end
from tally
where 
    N >= 2013 --start year

select * from @result
```